# How do I insert chars at multiple places in a string?

Tags: string, powershell, for-loop, insert

I want to insert ":" after every second character - the end result should look like this `51:40:2e:c0:11:0b:3e:3c`.

My solution

```
$s = "51402ec0110b3e3c"

for ($i = 2; $i -lt $s.Length; $i+=3)
{
$s.Insert($i,':')
}

Write-Host $s
```

returns

```
51:402ec0110b3e3c
51402:ec0110b3e3c
51402ec0:110b3e3c
51402ec0110:b3e3c
51402ec0110b3e:3c
51402ec0110b3e3c
```

Why is $s being returned multiple times when I only put Write-Host at the very end? Also, it looks like $s keeps returning to its original value after every loop, overwriting the previous loops...

I would've thought that the loop accomplishes the same as this:

```
$s = $sInsert(2,':').Insert(5,':').Insert(8,':').Insert(11,':').Insert(14,':').Insert(17,':').Insert(20,':')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [insert returns a new string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=net-5.0). It does not modify the string in place. So, you have to change

```
$s.Insert($i,':')
```

to

```
$s = $s.Insert($i,':')
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this without looping via the `-replace` operator:

```
$s = "51402ec0110b3e3c"
$s = $s -replace '..(?!$)','$0:'
```

A combination of `-split` and `-join` works too:

```
$s = "51402ec0110b3e3c"
$s = $s -split '(..)' -ne '' -join ':'
```

Comment: This is a life saver! Can you please explain the replace regex? (This should be more easily found in your Powershell-101 documentation.)

Answer (score 2):

an alternate method for converting a hex string to a colon-delimited string is to use the `-split` operator with a pattern that specifies two consecutive characters. this ...

```
$s = "51402ec0110b3e3c"
($s -split '(..)').Where({$_}) -join ':'
```

... will give this = `51:40:2e:c0:11:0b:3e:3c`.

the `.Where()` filters out the blank entries the split leaves behind. [*grin*]

take care,
lee